# Git Bash - Windows - Different font size between start screen launch and explorer launch

Tags: windows-8, bash, git, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on Windows 8.1

I see (at least) two different ways to launch Git Bash:

1) Start Screen -> Type Git Bash -> Press Enter

2) Windows Explorer -> Right Click Folder -> Select "Git Bash"

When I open the program with method 1 my fonts are small. 
When I open the program with method 2 my fonts are large. 
Both method seems to read my /etc/profile and other config correctly.

I prefer the larger fonts, so I want it to open with larger fonts every time.

What is the difference between launch methods? Why does this happen, and how can I make it use the large fonts every time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What is the difference between the launch methods?**

The first method runs Git Bash using a launch configuration whose default font size is sometimes too small for hi-res screens.
The second method also has its own independent launch configuration that's tied to your windows context menu, hence its possible to have different font size settings.

**Why does this happen?**

Not sure. In my case, both launch configurations appeared with small fonts. Only needed to modify the first.

**How can I make it use large fonts every time?**

In a nutshell - modify the launch configuration by editing the properties of your git-bash short-cut. To do that in windows 8 follow these steps:

- From your start screen navigate to your apps (click the down arrow right under the desktop icon, its located in the bottom-left of the screen)
- Scroll right till you get to the git-bash icon; right-click the icon and select 'pin to taskbar'
- Navigate to your desktop; hold down the Shift key and right-click the git bash icon on your taskbar and select 'properties'
- A dialog should pop-up; select the font tab and set the font-size
- Make sure to save your changes by clicking the 'apply' button; you can unpin the icon from your taskbar when done.

Comment: In Windows 10, launch Git Bash, click the icon in upper left of Git Bash, look for "Options" then Text on left side of options.

Answer (score 4):

To change default window size on MINGW64 or mintty

1. Right click on the bash screen
2. Option
3. Choose Window on the left
4. Change Columns, Rows size
5. Apply. Restart the bash to see the changes.